# how can I have access to property class in the Json object?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I want to access in class property and method

//sample code

```
export class MapComponent implements {

chartMap;

loadMap(){

   let setting={
      callBack:function(data){
         this.chartMap=data;   //<<<------not access my class property
      }
   }

}
}
```

not access my class property in json object

Comment: Also, there's no JSON anywhere in this question. JSON is a text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `this` context issue. when `setting.callBack()` is invoked, it is looking for chartMap in caller, not in the MapComponent object.

There are several way to do it. You can use Arrow function expression.

```ts
export class MapComponent implements {

  chartMap;

  loadMap() {

    let setting = {
      callBack: (data) => {
        this.chartMap = data;
      }
    }
  }
}
```